# MVC 4 Controller and Web Api controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am currently working on an MVC 4 project and i need to give acces to the database to the mobile apllication so i choosed to implement my Web services in Web Api to get a Json resulat .
The problem is i have many code redundancy ! the same code is existent in MVC controller and in the Web Api controller .

For exemple  the get procedure :

1- web api controller :

```
 public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return user;
    }
```

2-MVC controller

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

one is returning the User entity in JSon and the other return a view ! 
So how can use one Controller in the other to get rid of redandency ?

Comment: the real question should be, whether you shd access the dbContext directly in your Controller or through web api?. And that's totally your call.

Comment: I need the MVC controllers to work with my views and the web api controller to provide data access to the mobile Side wish is the work of another developper. @ManishMishra

Comment: I don't really see any problem here, they are two separate entities and should remain that way. If you really do want to stop the code duplication, then one thing you could do would be to update your normal controller to make calls to your API service, but that's totally your call

Comment: yes thats my question how could i call the API servir inside my cntroller

Comment: In your normal controller, use the `webclient` class to make a call to your API.

Comment: Or put your data access code in a repository class, and use that class in both your MVC controller and WebApi controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this question from the point of view of separation of concerns, both of the controllers have a different function (supplying JSON and markup respectively), but both need to make use of a common service: namely, data persistence.

For that reason, as @paul suggested in the comments, the repository pattern offers a good design to solve this problem. In your example, you may not seem to gain much, but as soon as your data retrieval and persistence logic becomes more complex, the repository will enforce consistency, reduce redundancy, and support more sophisticated patterns such as dependency injection.

Here's a simple repository:

```
interface IRepository
{
    User GetUser(int id);
}

public class MyRepository: IRepository
{
    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        return db.Users.Find(id);
    }
}
```

Api controller

```
public User GetUser(int id)
{
    var repo = new MyRepository();
    User user = repo.GetUser(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }
    return user;
}
```

MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    var repo = new MyRepository();
    User user = repo.GetUser(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As paul said this is all about separation of concerns. Paul provided you an example with a "logical service layer" which is an independent class library in your solution that your other Web Applications or desktop applications etc. reference it. Another example may be a "physical service layer" which is another Web Api Project in your solution, that contains all the service methods of your application. From your MVC project whenever you want a call to have your users, you create a new WebClient to call your web api's GetUser end points.

Answer (score 1):

You can just return JSON() from the MVC controller and avoid the usage of two frameworks. There is nothing wrong with that, and will keep your life simple.

```
public ActionResult GetUser(int id) // GetUser is the action name, or you can just use Index
{
    User user = db.Users.Find(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return Json(user);
}
```